# How to solve Nan Consumable Purchase error billing v 5

Tags: android, in-app-purchase

I am using the given code in my app for Nan Consumed Purchase.

```
    package com.education.saifpurchasedemo;

     import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
     import android.os.Bundle;
     import android.util.Log;
     import android.view.View;
     import android.widget.Button;
     import android.widget.TextView;

     import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
     import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

     import com.android.billingclient.api.AcknowledgePurchaseParams;
     import com.android.billingclient.api.BillingClient;
     import com.android.billingclient.api.BillingClientStateListener;
     import com.android.billingclient.api.BillingFlowParams;
     import com.android.billingclient.api.BillingResult;
     import com.android.billingclient.api.ProductDetails;
      import com.android.billingclient.api.ProductDetailsResponseListener;
     import com.android.billingclient.api.Purchase;
     import com.android.billingclient.api.QueryProductDetailsParams;
     import com.android.billingclient.api.QueryPurchasesParams;

      import java.util.ArrayList;
     import java.util.List;

         import android.os.Bundle;

       public class NonConsumable extends AppCompatActivity {
    private final String PRODUCT_PREMIUM = "lifetime";
    private final String NoAds = "NoAds";
    private ArrayList<String> purchaseItemIDs = new ArrayList<String>() {{
    add(PRODUCT_PREMIUM);
    add(NoAds);
   }};

private String TAG = "iapSample";

private BillingClient billingClient;

Button btn_premium, btn_restore;
TextView tv_status;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_non_consumable);
    billingClient = BillingClient.newBuilder(this)
            .enablePendingPurchases()
            .setListener(
                    (billingResult, list) -> {

                        if (billingResult.getResponseCode() == BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.OK && list != null) {
                            for (Purchase purchase : list) {

                                Log.d(TAG, "Response is OK");
                                handlePurchase(purchase);
                            }
                        } else {

                            Log.d(TAG, "Response NOT OK");
                        }
                    }
            ).build();

    //start the connection after initializing the billing client
    establishConnection();
    init();
}

void init() {
    btn_premium = this.findViewById(R.id.btn_premium);
    btn_restore = this.findViewById(R.id.btn_restore);
    tv_status = this.findViewById(R.id.tv_status);

    btn_premium.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            GetSingleInAppDetail();
        }
    });

    btn_restore.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            restorePurchases();
        }
    });
}


void establishConnection() {
    billingClient.startConnection(new BillingClientStateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onBillingSetupFinished(@NonNull BillingResult billingResult) {
            if (billingResult.getResponseCode() == BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.OK) {

                // The BillingClient is ready. You can query purchases here.

                //Use any of function below to get details upon successful connection

                // GetSingleInAppDetail();
                //GetListsInAppDetail();

                Log.d(TAG, "Connection Established");
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onBillingServiceDisconnected() {
            // Try to restart the connection on the next request to
            // Google Play by calling the startConnection() method.
            Log.d(TAG, "Connection NOT Established");
            establishConnection();
        }
    });
}

/*
 *
 * The official examples use an ImmutableList for some reason to build the query,
 * but you don't actually need to use that.
 * The setProductList method just takes List<Product> as its input, it does not require 
  ImmutableList.
 *
 * */

/*
 * If you have API < 24, you could just make an ArrayList instead.
 * */

void GetSingleInAppDetail() {
    ArrayList<QueryProductDetailsParams.Product> productList = new ArrayList<>();

    //Set your In App Product ID in setProductId()
    productList.add(
            QueryProductDetailsParams.Product.newBuilder()
                    .setProductId(PRODUCT_PREMIUM)
                    .setProductType(BillingClient.ProductType.INAPP)
                    .build()
    );

    QueryProductDetailsParams params = QueryProductDetailsParams.newBuilder()
            .setProductList(productList)
            .build();

    billingClient.queryProductDetailsAsync(params, new ProductDetailsResponseListener() {
        @Override
        public void onProductDetailsResponse(@NonNull BillingResult billingResult, @NonNull List<ProductDetails> list) {

            //Do Anything that you want with requested product details

            //Calling this function here so that once products are verified we can start the purchase behavior.
            //You can save this detail in separate variable or list to call them from any other location
            //Create another function if you want to call this in establish connections' success state
            LaunchPurchaseFlow(list.get(0));


        }
    });
}


void GetListsInAppDetail() {
    ArrayList<QueryProductDetailsParams.Product> productList = new ArrayList<>();

    //Set your In App Product ID in setProductId()
    for (String ids : purchaseItemIDs) {
        productList.add(
                QueryProductDetailsParams.Product.newBuilder()
                        .setProductId(ids)
                        .setProductType(BillingClient.ProductType.INAPP)
                        .build());
    }

    QueryProductDetailsParams params = QueryProductDetailsParams.newBuilder()
            .setProductList(productList)
            .build();

    billingClient.queryProductDetailsAsync(params, new ProductDetailsResponseListener() {
        @Override
        public void onProductDetailsResponse(@NonNull BillingResult billingResult, @NonNull List<ProductDetails> list) {

            for (ProductDetails li : list) {
                Log.d(TAG, "IN APP item Price" + li.getOneTimePurchaseOfferDetails().getFormattedPrice());
            }
            //Do Anything that you want with requested product details
        }
    });
}

void LaunchPurchaseFlow(ProductDetails productDetails) {
    ArrayList<BillingFlowParams.ProductDetailsParams> productList = new ArrayList<>();

    productList.add(
            BillingFlowParams.ProductDetailsParams.newBuilder()
                    .setProductDetails(productDetails)
                    .build());

    BillingFlowParams billingFlowParams = BillingFlowParams.newBuilder()
            .setProductDetailsParamsList(productList)
            .build();

    billingClient.launchBillingFlow(this, billingFlowParams);
}

void handlePurchase(Purchase purchases) {
    if (!purchases.isAcknowledged()) {
        billingClient.acknowledgePurchase(AcknowledgePurchaseParams
                .newBuilder()
                .setPurchaseToken(purchases.getPurchaseToken())
                .build(), billingResult -> {

            if (billingResult.getResponseCode() == BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.OK) {
                for (String pur : purchases.getProducts()) {
                    if (pur.equalsIgnoreCase(PRODUCT_PREMIUM)) {
                        Log.d("TAG", "Purchase is successful" + pur);
                        tv_status.setText("Yay! Purchased");
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

}

void restorePurchases() {

    billingClient = BillingClient.newBuilder(this).enablePendingPurchases().setListener((billingResult, list) -> {
    }).build();
    final BillingClient finalBillingClient = billingClient;
    billingClient.startConnection(new BillingClientStateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onBillingServiceDisconnected() {
        }

        @Override
        public void onBillingSetupFinished(@NonNull BillingResult billingResult) {

            if (billingResult.getResponseCode() == BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.OK) {
                finalBillingClient.queryPurchasesAsync(
                        QueryPurchasesParams.newBuilder().setProductType(BillingClient.ProductType.INAPP).build(), (billingResult1, list) -> {
                            if (billingResult1.getResponseCode() == BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.OK) {
                                if (list.size() > 0) {

                                    Log.d("TAG", "IN APP SUCCESS RESTORE: " + list);
                                    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {

                                        if (list.get(i).getProducts().contains(PRODUCT_PREMIUM)) {
                                            tv_status.setText("Premium Restored");
                                            Log.d("TAG", "Product id " + PRODUCT_PREMIUM + " will restore here");
                                        }

                                    }
                                } else {
                                    tv_status.setText("Nothing found to Restored");
                                    Log.d("TAG", "In APP Not Found To Restore");
                                }
                            }
                        });
            }
        }
       });
       }
       }
```

I first created a demo of my app and then uploaded it to Google Play with the product ID listed below. As shown in the image.

[image]

I used the link that Google Play gave me as an app tester on a device that only had the same email login.
Now the problem is that when I click for purchase, I see the relevant price but when I proceed, I see the listed error. " Something wend wrong - Your transaction can't be completed ". Can you please tell me where is the mistake?

Comment: There is no one there who can understand my code and guide me where there is a mistake.

Comment: I have also added following Dependencies "  implementation 'com.android.billingclient:billing:5.1.0'"

Comment: All the code I mentioned is correct. After a short wait, the purchase price on Google Play was adjusted. Due to which the whole problem was solved. Based on my experience, if anyone needs my help, I am here.